# Appointment system, checking if person is availaible at particular time

Tags: php

i am working on an appointment system, the problem i am facing is in a function where i want to check if the *person* with whom *someone* wants to book an appointment is available at that time or not.

each *person* has fixed daily time slot for example 02:00:00 to 04:30:00 during which *anyone* can contact him/her, now when booking appointment, i wanna check if *person* is available at the time when *someone* is willing to book an appointment or not.

here is the code:

```
    $strtTime = $PA[0]['starttime'];   //02:00:00
    $endTime = $PA[0]['endtime'];    //04:30:00        

    $expectedTime = date('g:i:s', strtotime($dteTime));   // $dteTime = 2010-12-31 02:30


    if($strtTime < $expectedTime && $endTime > $expectedTime) // the second condition is returning false
    {
        echo "PAA is available";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "PAA is not available at that time slot.";
        exit();           
    }
```

Comment: *$dteTime* is the passed value

Answer (score 0):

`date('g:i:s'` return 2:30:00

04:30:00 > 2:30:00 is false, because of alpha sort ("04" is < "2")

So change `date('g:i:s'` to `date('H:i:s'`

Comment: i changed date('g:i:s' to date('H:i:s'
now let,
$strtTime = 02:00:00
$endTime= 04:30:00
$expectedTime = 02:30:00
04:30:00 > 02:30:00 is still false, is their any better solution?